# How can I scroll down a Power BI table on a webpage in order to scrape its content using Python + Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

I'm trying to scrape a table of a Power BI dashboard website using the Selenium library. I've already made some progress, such as clicking on a page filter and scraping the initial data. However, to fully accomplish my task, I need to scrape all the table content, and for this, I should scroll down the table (while I scrape the data) until all the data is fully loaded. And the scrolling part is where I'm getting stuck. I've tried some different things, and none of them worked.

Here is my code so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYTgyZTI0NjgtNGFhYi00MWI3LTg4YTUtNWY2MTAyMjUxZjI2IiwidCI6ImI4YzI1OTMyLTVlNzYtNGIyYi05YzUzLWQ0MTc0NWU5YzkyZCJ9")

table_xpath = r"//*[@id='pvExplorationHost']/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[5]/transform/div/div[3]/div/div/visual-modern"

filter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pvExplorationHost']/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[1]/transform/div/div[3]/div/div/visual-modern/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]")))

sleep(3)

filter.click()

table_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, table_xpath)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500);", table_element)

sleep(10)
```

and the part where I try to scrape that (and it works!):

```
list1 = []
for j in range (1,30):
    data_teste = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, table_xpath + "/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[" + str(j) +"]")]
    list1.append(data_teste)    
print(list1)
```

But anything happens on the scroll part, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.
Can anyone explain how I can make this work?

Comment: Seems wrong (in a strange/why kind of way) to be scraping data from a power bi report. I am curious to learn more about your use case.

Comment: It's public data from a Brazilian government education program. However, this year they made the unfortunate decision to only make the Power BI dashboard available, instead of providing the CSV file.